# Want to know use of

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class PalindromeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "test";
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            stack.push(input.charAt(i));
        }

        String reverseInput = "";

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            reverseInput += stack.pop();
        }

        if (input.equals(reverseInput))
            System.out.println("Yo! that is a palindrome.");
        else
            System.out.println("No! that isn't a palindrome.");

    }
}
```

In above program what is the purpose of: 
reverseInput += stack.pop();
What happen when you assign,this .i confuse with this line,,can any one Explain??

Answer (score 0):

It simply removes the topmost character of the stack and appends it to the String `reverseInput` using Java's usual String concatenation. Because it's inside that loop, it'll remove characters until the stack is empty. That's what actually reverses the input String (the first character of the original is the bottommost in the stack, so it's the last character of the reversed String).

[See java.util.Stack JavaDoc here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)